# col-right sidebar border height

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

On my products page I have set the layout to be 2 columns with right bar. What I am trying to do is make the col-right sidebar border height to be the same as the col-main. I have tried doing this in the CSS and have been only able to do it by manually setting the pixel height. Obviously the main class and the col-main class heights are set by the content. I was just wondering if there is a way to set the col-right sidebar class border height to automatically be the same as the col-main class?

[image]

Comment: can u share the link of the site?

Comment: http://www.gwyneddleigh.com.au/store/

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript Luke.
add this in any layout files (untested code, syntax errors may appear...but you get the idea):

```
<default><!-- if you need it in only a specific page use the appropriate layout handle for example `cms_index_index` for homepage -->
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text" name="height-fixer">
             <action method="setText">
                 <text><![CDATA[
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                         document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
                             var mainCol = $$('.col-main');
                             var rightCol = $$('.col-right');
                             if (typeof mainCol[0] != "undefined" && typeof rightCol[0] != "undefined") {
                                 if (mainCol[0].getHeight() > rightCol[0].getHeight()) {
                                     rightCol[0].setStyle({height:mainCol[0].getHeight() + 'px'});
                                 }
                             }
                         });
                     </script>
                 ]]></text>
             </action>
        <block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Marius, i appreciate it. The only problem is that I am not very good with Javascript (yet). I did add this code to the local.xml but it didn't seem to work and it messed up the other things that were in the local.xml. I have also realised in my continued testing that  there are situations ie in the shopping cart, where the col-right sidebar is longer than the col-main, so I don't know if the code example would mess that particular situation. but thanks again for your help.

Comment: The js code above should handle the case when the main column is smaller than the right col. In that case, nothing should happen.